# Streaming messages to multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a single master topic and multiple predicates each of which has an output topic associated with it. I want to send each record to ALL topics that whose predicate resolves to true. I am using Luwak to test which predicates a record satisfies (to use this library you evaluate a document with a list of predicates and it tells you which ones matched - i.e. I only call it once to get the list of satisfied predicates).

I am trying to use Kafka Streams for this but there doesn't seem to be the appropriate method on KStream (KStream#branch only routes a record to a single topic).

One possible approach is as follows:

```
Stream from master
Map the values into a format with the original content and the list of matching predicates
Stream to an intermediate with-matches topic

For each predicate/output topic
    Stream from intermediate with-matches topic
    Filter "does list of matches predicates contain predicate ID"
    Map the values to just the original content
    Stream to corresponding output topic
```

Such an intermediate topic seems "clunky" though. Any better suggestions?

I am using:

- Kafka v0.10.1.1
- Luwak v1.4.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can simple apply multiple filters in parallel to the same `KStream` instance:

```java
KStream stream = ...

stream.filter(new MyPredicate1()).to("output-topic-1");
stream.filter(new MyPredicate2()).to("output-topic-2");
stream.filter(new MyPredicate3()).to("output-topic-3");
// ... as as many as you need
```

Each record will be sent to each predicate once -- it's conceptually a broadcast to all filters, but records will not be physically replicated, so there is no memory overhead.

Comment: branch can also be used.

Comment: @CyberKnight Not really for the use case describe above: `branch()` only allows you to put every record into at most one output stream (ie, you can put records into different topics), while the use case describe is to write each record into multiple output stream (multiple != different).

Comment: I see. Then the answer provided would suffice. You are right!

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I would like to have an orthogonal topic populated without affecting the original stream and it's destination topic, will this work?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Maybe start a new question with more details?

Comment: Will this provide collective EOS (exactly once semantics)? e.g. an error before publishing to output-topic-1 will stop the entire flow and no more publishing happen. OR the other case where error for one topic does not affect the event publishing for other topics?

Comment: For the stateless case as above, EOS would cover the full processing of a single (or multiple) input records.