# How to add workflow to Kafka messages?

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka, workflow

I am migrating my java project from Rabbit MQ to Kafka (for some reasons).

However, I am facing one difficulty.

In current workflow, I post all the messages to rabbit mq exchange, and based on the routing key of the messages, the messages are redirected to one or more queues.
I want to retain the same functionality in Kafka also. ( I know kafka is not originally suited for it but I want a workaround).

Basically, I want something like this: whenever a message is received by a topic, based on the meta present in the message, the message should be redirected to other set of topics.

What is the fastest way to achieve this? I would prefer python or java solution

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Streaming messages to multiple topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388525/streaming-messages-to-multiple-topics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you publish Kafka messages with keys they will be directed to topic partitions such that all similar keys go to the same partition.

Alternatively you can use Kafka Streams to read an input topic and route messages to a set of output topics based on the keys provided with the messages.

Comment: Is there any tutorial or blog on this?

Comment: Is it possible to use 1 topic as exchange. Whenever a message is recieved on the topic with a certain key-value pair, rediret it to a particualr set of topics?

Comment: Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388525/streaming-messages-to-multiple-topics