# Kafka Streams to multiple output topics: implication for delivery guarantees

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Looking at the accepted answer for [Streaming messages to multiple topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388525/streaming-messages-to-multiple-topics)

How is the delivery guarantee impacted by such a fan-out operation. Do we get at-least-once-delivery to each output topic?